# Clojure loop receiving IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer clojure.lang.APersistentVector.invoke

Tags: clojure

I'm stuck trying to get a simple loop in Clojure to work and I don't know how to proceed to get rid of the exception. I'm trying to write an `arrange` function to `exchange` items in a vector. Here is the code.

```
(defn exchange [v i] 
  (let [[src dst] i]
    (assoc v dst (v src) src (v dst))))

(defn arrange []
  (loop [idxs [0 0] 
         deck [\a \b \c \d \e] 
         pts [[0 1] [2 3] [4 1]]]
    (println idxs deck pts)
    (empty? pts)
      deck
      (recur (first pts) (exchange deck idxs) (rest pts))))    

;(arrange)
;[b e d c a]
```

If I remove the println, I don't see anything in the REPL. I came from COBOL so you know I'm struggling to pick this up:) Any suggestions to make this more idiomatic would be appreciated.

6/11-
This is the corrected code. `arrange` should have only two paramaters in the loop.

```
(defn arrange []
  (loop [deck [\a \b \c \d \e] 
         lst [[0 1] [2 3] [4 1]]]
    (if (empty? lst)
      deck
      (recur (exchange deck (first lst)) (rest lst)))))
```

or even better, use `(reduce exchange deck lst)` instead as per @Magos!

Comment: I see you've already got a good answer on your `loop`, so I just thought I'd mention that`exchange` is a binary operator of the kind `reduce` is designed for (takes a "value so far" and another value of an independent type, produces another "value so far"), and your `loop` in `arrange` is therefore basically reimplementing `reduce` for one specific operator. You could alternatively do this as `(reduce exchange [\a \b \c \d \e] [[0 1] [2 3] [4 1]])`.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of suggestion I was looking for! Thank you so much for taking the time to comment on my question.

Comment: if I change pts to [[1 4] [1 3] [4 0]] then `arrange` returns (\b \e \c \d \a) but `(reduce exchange [\a \b \c \d \e] [[1 4] [1 3] [4 0]])` returns [\b \d \c \e \a] so arrange and reduce+exchange appear to work a little differently. Maybe there is still a way to utilize reduce though?

Comment: I get the same results as reduce if I leaves the test as `(if (empty? pts)`.

Comment: That's odd, then. Using `arrange` with @bsvingens' suggestions and your new `pts` I get `[\b \d \c \e \a]`, like with `reduce`. Could you maybe have also changed the initial binding to `idxs`? If so you need to add that vector to the front of your arguments to `reduce` to have the same effect. (`[0 0]` gives an `exchange` that doesn't lead to any changes, though, so I didn't include it)

Comment: I figured out today that your suggestion is right if `arrange` is coded correctly (see above), but (reduce exchange deck lst) works better! @user1571406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `if`, and you need to end the loop on `idxs`, not `pts` (or you will miss the final index pair):

```
(if (empty? idxs)
  deck
  (recur (first pts) (exchange deck idxs) (rest pts)))
```

should work better.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was simple but I couldn't see it. Also for pointing out the error in my conditional. I tried to +1 but it says I need 15 reputation :(